# How to change from Stream<arrays[String]> to Stream<Strings> java 8

Tags: java, string, java-stream

I cannot convert Stream of arrays(of Strings) to Stream of Strings.

```
public static List<String> getFirstNames(List<String> names){
        return names.stream()
                .map(x->x.split("\\s[A-Za-z]+"))
                .map(elem-> new String())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I have a List of Strings on input including First Name and Last Name.
On output there has to be List of First Names.

Comment: you got use the `flatMap` method of your stream of Arrays

Comment: Where is the array mentioned in your title? I don’t see it in your code nor in your question text. For best answers please clarify.

Comment: mapping using split method gives me stream of arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static List<String> getFirstNames(List<String> names){
    return names.stream()
            .map(x->Arrays.asList(x.split("\\s[A-Za-z]+")))
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

flatMap do the job

Optimal solution:

```
public static List<String> getFirstNames(List<String> names){
    return names.stream()
            .map(x->x.split("\\s+")[0])
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: please copy as it is, notice that I used **Arrays.asList** (x.split("\\s[A-Za-z]+")) so it is Collection.stream(List<String>)

Answer (score 2):

Use `.map(x->x.split("\\s[A-Za-z]+")[0])` and leave out the second unnecessary `map`. You want the first element of the array, and it's a String. No reason to pass the full array to a second `map()`.

But if you really want to, then the second map would have to be `.map(arr -> arr[0])`. You don't want a new `String`, it already exists.

Also as this is basic syntax (well not the streams, but accessing arrays and using Strings), brush up [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/), or you'll keep tripping over simple errors.

Splitting on a space (`split(" ")`) is more readable mind you, unless you have some reason to use the more cumbersome version?

Comment: Wouldn't you want to split on " " to separate the first names from the last names?

Comment: @kenny_k oh yeah I wasn't paying attention to the regex.

Comment: using [0] will only return first name from the array, and I want the stream of firstNames

Comment: using this split("\\s[A-Za-z]+") I wanted to delete lastName, dont know if I think right

Comment: @DamazyKowalski there's no "delete". You use `split()` to split the string according to some text or pattern. Then you get the parts in an array. Splitting on a space with `.split(" ")` gives you an array of size 2, with the first name in index 0 and last name at index 1. I recommend reading the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) and of course the tutorials, since you're a beginner and you still seem to have misunderstandings about what the code does.

Comment: Thank You, I know I am beginner but having this String : "Damazy Kowalski" and using split with regex "\\s[A-Za-z]+" I get String "Damazy". So why can't I name it delete?

Comment: @DamazyKowalski you can name it whatever you want, but other people won't understand you.

Answer (score 2):

If your list contains elements like `"FirstName LastName"` 
You can use the `substring()` method to extract the first names `s.substring(0, s.indexOf(" ")`

Try this:

```
public static List<String> getFirstNames(List<String> names){
    return names.stream().map(s -> s.substring(0, s.indexOf(" "))).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

If your list contains single word elements:

```
public static List<String> getFirstNames(List<String> names){
    return names.stream().map(s -> s.indexOf(" ")>0 ? s.substring(0, s.indexOf(" ")) : s).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: This doesn't handle single word elements like the regex, but throws an exception when there's no space in the String.

Comment: @Kayaman But OP says 'Strings on input including First Name and Last Name.'

Answer (score -3):

Here is the example using Arrays::stream with flatmap

```
List<String> firstNames =
            Arrays.asList("Aman Singh","Raj Malhotra").stream()
                    .map(word -> word.split("\\s[A-Za-z]+"))
                    .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                    .collect(toList());

    System.out.println("First names are" + firstNames);
```

Comment: This one is a complete misunderstanding of the question.